# User ID config for GA4. Before a user-id becomes available, should User ID field in DataLayer be left as blank?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a website where a user-id becomes available mid website session when the user begins an application process.
For GA4 > GA config type > Fields to set > user_id field that is appended to all page  / screen views, what should the DL value be for user-id before it becomes available? Should it be left as blank?
Example datalayer:
Before user-id is available,
user_id: ''
After user-id becomes available,
user_id: 1234

Thanks.
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9442095

Answer (score 0):

It must be `undefined`. The best way to set it as undefined is to remove the userId parameter from the dataLayer if it has no value.

Comment: If you check this link, it says adding user-id to the config tag in GA4 and adding the config to all page views. Effectively, user-id val would be blank for page/screen views before a user logins and would then populate once this action has been completed. However, for this method, the DL var has to be consistently available for the Config section to pick up the val  https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9442095